# Bootstrap footer going up when zoomed

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, footer

Guys I am new to web development and I am creating a website, got stuck in footer. I want my footer to be stick at bottom when zoomed in and be at bottom but when I zoom in my footer is going up as shown in screenshot. I dont know what is problem, searched it in google but couldn't find solution.Help
[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xmgE.jpg)
ALL CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg justify-content-end">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto container justify-content-center">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT ME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">PROJECTS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>


    <footer class="page-footer font-small blue pt-4">
        <div class="container-fluid text-center text-md-left">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase"><b>About</b></h4>
                    <p>Bright World is a multinational corporation headquartered<br>in Pakistan, one of the largest
                        electronics companies in the<br>world, currently focused in the area of lighting. It
                        was<br>founded in  by Gerard Mark and his father<br>Frederik, with their
                        first products being light bulbs.</p>
                </div>
                <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-3">
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase"><b>Brands</b></h4>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled footer-links">
                        <li>
                            <a href="Philips Page.html">Philips</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="GE Lighting page.html">Ge Lighting</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Nichia Page.html">Nichia</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Osaka Lighting Page.html">Osaka Lighting</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Epistar Page.html">Epistar</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>


                <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase"><b>Links</b></h4>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled footer-links">
                        <li>
                            <a href="BrightWorld homepage.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="BrightWorld gallerypage.html">Gallery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="BrightWorld aboutpage.html">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="BrightWorld contactpage.html">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© Copyright 2021 BrightWorld
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>

<style>
    body {
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }

    body>.container {
        padding-top: 60px;
    }

    a {
        color: black;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
    }

    .navbar {
        background-color: coral;
    }

    .navbar-toggler-icon {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    }

    .nav-link {
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        transition: 0.1s;
    }

    .nav-link:hover {
        color: rgb(220, 217, 217);
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    /* 
    ul li {
        padding-left: 30px;
    } */

    body {
        height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    }

    .page-footer {
        background-color: #1B1B1B;
        color: white;

    }

    .footer-copyright {
        background-color: #090909;
        color: white;
    }

    .footer-links a {
        padding: 10px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #404040;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
        display: block;
        transition: color 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: border 0.5s ease-in-out;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .footer-links a:hover {
        color: aqua;
        border-bottom: 1px solid aqua;
    }
</style>

</html>
```

HTML:

```
<footer class="page-footer font-small blue pt-4">
        <div class="container-fluid text-center text-md-left">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase"><b>About</b></h4>
                    <p>Bright World is a multinational corporation headquartered<br>in Pakistan, one of the largest
                        electronics companies in the<br>world, currently focused in the area of lighting. It
                        was<br>founded in Pakistan in 1891 by Gerard Mark and his father<br>Frederik, with their
                        first products being light bulbs.</p>
                </div>
                <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-3">
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase"><b>Brands</b></h4>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled footer-links">
                        <li>
                            <a href="Philips Page.html">Philips</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="GE Lighting page.html">Ge Lighting</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Nichia Page.html">Nichia</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Osaka Lighting Page.html">Osaka Lighting</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Epistar Page.html">Epistar</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>


                <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase"><b>Links</b></h4>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled footer-links">
                        <li>
                            <a href="BrightWorld homepage.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="BrightWorld gallerypage.html">Gallery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="BrightWorld aboutpage.html">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="BrightWorld contactpage.html">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© Copyright 2021 BrightWorld
        </div>
    </footer>
```

CSS:

```
.page-footer {
        background-color: #1B1B1B;
        color: white;
        position: relative;
    }
    .footer-copyright {
        background-color: #090909;
        color: white;
    }
    .footer-links a {
        padding: 10px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #404040;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
        display: block;
        transition: color 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: color 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: color 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: border 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: border 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: border 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: border 0.5s ease-in-out;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .footer-links a:hover {
        color: aqua;
        border-bottom: 1px solid aqua;
    }
```

Before zooming in chrome:
[image: screenshot]
After zooming in 125% in chrome:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please try to set min height in content area div like min-height: 1080px;

Comment: This issues get due to content area is short and your device height is big so.

Comment: I set min-height to 1080px to footer and now it's height is so big.

Comment: Set height you want for your device

Comment: another way is height is set vh and minus your header and footer this is set auto in every device.

Comment: my monitor is 1080p so i set it to 1080px

Comment: how to set to vh-header footer?

Comment: .content-area { height: calc(100vh - 100px); }

check your header height and footer height than total and minus

Comment: what is content-area class ? I am really a beginner

Comment: and how to check header height and footer height

Comment: content-area means without header footer area div. check after header tag like main div all content put code in that div

Comment: i have no main div tag but a body tag in which my all content are

Comment: ok have any link or screenshot of code

Comment: yes screenshot is atatched

Comment: Code screenshot not a out put.

Comment: I am editing my post showing you full code.

Comment: I have posted my full code.

Comment: are . you there?

Comment: yes i checking..

Comment: I post answer and i will back within 1 hour wait please i can help too you.

Comment: ok friend yes i am waiting

Comment: Done? set height 413px minus value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check header and footer height and than total and minus.

how to check height following step:

- Inspect element on  tag and hover on footer tag and seen height same as follow  tag.

[image]

```css
.content-area {
    height: cal(100vh - 413px);
}

remove: 

body {
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

```html
<section class="content-area">
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</section>

replace to

<div class="container">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep footer in bottom do this changes.
Remove '<br>' before container div. Add full-height class to the container div

```
<div class="container full-height">
   {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Remove this styling

```
body {
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

And add this styling

```
.container.full-height {
    height: calc(100vh - 413px);
 }
```

413px value came from total height of header and footer.

Here is the JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/9f2vy3wr/5/ 
 Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have marked your post as answered and you solved my problem but when I implemented your solution another problem has arisen and that is when I switch my website into Mobile mode my content is hiding behind my footer.

Comment: In the fiddle we have added style at the end for mobile.

Comment: Now when I switch to mobile mode it is displaying as I wanted but in normal desktop mode my some last content is hiding behind footer and some content is displaying on footer.

Comment: can you help me with this .

Comment: Give overflow-y:scroll; in .container.full-height style to view other content

Comment: I did it worked in a way but the chrome default side line is appearing on my website and that's not good.

Comment: What line is appearing?

Comment: The one with the help of which we scroll down on browser, It is appearing on website.

Comment: Yes, that will show because to keep footer stick at bottom we have minus the height of it from 100vh to the container. So, in order to view other content we will have to set the scrollbar.

Comment: But i dont want that can you please...help

Comment: try changing body>.container { padding-top: 60px; } to body>.container { margin: 50px auto; padding: 0; } We think this is the final solution.

Comment: I tried but when I zoom in my content is appearing on footer.

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot after adding our changes?

Comment: I have added screenshots of before and after zooming. I think you are resizing your browser to mobile modes for checking. But my problem is when Zoom In not Resizing.

Comment: Are. you there?